# How to cache Mono object

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following code:

```
final T savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
entityCacheService.putIntoCache(entity.getId(), savedEntity);
```

Now I made my repository reactive. My question is how to make the cache store now mono and flux.

```
final Mono<T> savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
entityCacheService.putIntoCache(entity.getId(), <<What here>>);
```

I came across the following [Mono and Flux Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156424/spring-webflux-and-cacheable-proper-way-of-caching-result-of-mono-flux-type) but it's only for lookup and since I am also a beginner in reactive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way in your case is to rely on the fact that the `save` operation returns a `Mono<T>` that emits the saved entity.

You could thus use `doOnNext` to also put that entity in the cache whenever it is saved in DB:

```
final Mono<T> savedEntity = repository.save(entity)
    .doOnNext(entity -> entityCacheService.putIntoCache(entity.getId(), entity);
```

The resulting `Mono<T>` will both save *then* cache the entity whenever it is subscribed to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For flux can i do like following `savedEntities.collectList().doOnNext(e -> e.stream().forEach(c -> entityCacheService.putIntoCache(c.getId(), c)));` if `savedEntities` is Flux

Comment: No, doOnEach will be invoked for each saved entity so it is already doing a job similar to forEach

Comment: you mean like following `savedEntities.doOnEach(s -> {
   if (s.isOnNext()) {
    T e = s.get();
    entityCacheService.putIntoCache(e.getId(), e);
   }
  });` ?

Comment: Ah sorry i meant doOnNext like in my first example