# Can I use SpringWebflux with hibernate or not?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-webflux

I am trying to build a REST application that may one day be used by potentially millions of clients. Keeping that in mind, we expect a lot of requests to come in together. I am wondering if it will be apt to use Hibernate or spring-flux for this. Our database model is highly relational and hence we have had to reject mongo and other non-relational databases. A few questions I have are:

1. Can spring-webflux and hibernate be used together?
2. If the answer to question 1 is No, does spring-flux have a caching feature like hibernate?
3. If the answer to question 1 is No, will spring flux's non blocking approach be faster than hibernate consistently over time?
4. What could be some benefits of spring-flux/hibernate that I might be missing to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use both `R2DBC` & `Hibernate Reative`.
But ***if you are migrating from hibernate based project to webflux***, I recommended you to use the `Hibernate Reactive`. it's all same as the old hibernate and you can use all of the native hibernate annotations, except some minor changes that you can find in the [Document](http://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/).

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Can spring-webflux and hibernate be used together?

Yes of course. **BUT** the currently Hibernate is blocking-IO so you loose the non-blocking reactive character of `spring-webflux`. Oliver Gierke (Spring Data project lead) recently announced a reactive Java database connectivity (https://github.com/r2dbc), but this is currently not available.

> 2. If the answer to question 1 is No, does spring-flux have a caching feature like hibernate?

This question is already solved in an other Stack Overflow question: [Spring Webflux and @Cacheable - proper way of caching result of Mono / Flux type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156424/spring-webflux-and-cacheable-proper-way-of-caching-result-of-mono-flux-type)

> 3. If the answer to question 1 is No, will spring flux's non blocking approach be faster than hibernate consistently over time?

This question is hard to answer in front. General I/O related stuff is more "expensive" and will drain your performance.

Comment: If my application is build using Spring mvc and hibernate and now I switch from spring mvc to spring webflux, can it badly affect my application? 
For the existing code, I don't want that to be reactive. I just want some new REST endpoints to be reactive.