# Alternatives to @Cacheable with spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I need to cache data coming from a `ReactiveMongoRepository`. The data gets updated roughly twice a year, so I don't care about expiring the cache.

Since we [can't use @Cacheable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156424/spring-webflux-and-cacheable-proper-way-of-caching-result-of-mono-flux-type) with a flux, I'd like to find a straightforward, easy way to store the data coming from Mongo to redis, and use that data if present, else store it and serve the original data.

Is there are more straightforward way to do so than

```
  @GetMapping
  public Flux<AvailableInspection> getAvailableInspectionsRedis() {
    AtomicInteger ad = new AtomicInteger();
    return availableInspectionReactiveRedisOperations.opsForZSet().range("availableInspections", Range.<Long>from(Range.Bound.inclusive(0L)).to(Range.Bound.inclusive(-1L)))
        .switchIfEmpty(availableInspectionMongoRepository.findAll().map(e -> {
          availableInspectionReactiveRedisOperations.opsForZSet().add("availableInspections", e, ad.getAndIncrement()).block();
          return e;
        }));
  }
```

What I'm looking for explicitly is an option that lets me cache the data just as the @Cacheable annotation would do it. I'm looking for a generic solution to be able to cache any kind of flux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt there is an off-the-shelf solution for this problem.
However, you can easily build your own interface for getting generic cached objects and loading them to cache:

```
public interface GetCachedOrLoad<T> {

  Flux<T> getCachedOrLoad(String key, Flux<T> loader, Class<? extends T> clazz);
}
```

Each class that requires this functionality will just inject it via constructor and use it as follows:

```
public class PersistedObjectRepository {

  private final GetCachedOrLoad<PersistedObject> getCachedOrLoad;

  public PersistedObjectRepository(final GetCachedOrLoad<PersistedObject> getCachedOrLoad) {
    this.getCachedOrLoad = getCachedOrLoad;
  }

  public Flux<PersistedObject> queryPersistedObject(final String key) {
    return getCachedOrLoad.getCachedOrLoad(key, queryMongoDB(key), PersistedObject.class);
  }

  private Flux<PersistedObject> queryMongoDB(String key) {
    // use reactivemongo api to retrieve Flux<PersistedObject>
  }
}
```

And then you'll need to create an object implementing `GetCachedOrLoad<T>` and make it available for dependency injection.

```
public class RedisCache<T> implements GetCachedOrLoad<T> {

  private final Function<String, Flux<String>> getFromCache;
  private final BiConsumer<String, String> loadToCache;
  private final Gson gson;

  public RedisCache(Gson gson, RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> redisCommands) {
    this.getFromCache = key -> redisCommands.lrange(key, 0, -1);
    this.loadToCache = redisCommands::lpush;
    this.gson = gson;
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<T> getCachedOrLoad(final String key, Flux<T> loader, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    final Flux<T> cacheResults = getFromCache.apply(key)
      .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, clazz));
    return cacheResults.switchIfEmpty(
      loader.doOnNext(value -> loadToCache.accept(key, gson.toJson(value))));
  }
}
```

Hope this is generic enough :) .
PS. This is not a production-ready implementation and needs to be tuned for your own needs like adding exception-handling, customizing json serialization and so on.